# How do I remove a string that starts with '@' and ends with a blank character by using regular expressions in Python?

Tags: python, python-re

So I have this text:

"@Natalija What a wonderful day, isn't it @Kristina123 ?"

I tried to remove these two substrings that start with the character '@' by using re.sub function but it didn't work.

How do I remove the susbstring that starts with this character?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: `"(@[\w]+)"` is the pattern to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
import re
text = "@Natalija What a wonderful day, isn't it @Kristina123 ?"
t = re.sub('@.*? ', '', text)
print(t)
```

OUTPUT :

```
What a wonderful day, isn't it ?
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

- @ matches the character @
- \w+ matches any word character as many times as possible, so it stops at blank character

Code:

```
import re

regex = r"@\w+"
subst = "XXX"

test_str = "@Natalija What a wonderful day, isn't it @Kristina123 ?"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

print (result)
```

output:

```
XXX What a wonderful day, isn't it XXX ?
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it with `re.sub()`, it would be something like this:

```
import re

text = "@Natalija What a wonderful day, isn't it @Kristina123 ?"

output = re.sub('@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s','',text)

print(output) # Output: What a wonderful day, isn't it ?
```

- @ matches the @ character
- [a-zA-Z0-9] matches alphanumerical (uppercase and lowercase)
- "+" means "one or more" (otherwise it would match only one of those characters)
- \s matches whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this can also be done without using the module re. You can first split the sentence into words. Then remove the words containing the @ character and finally join the words into a new sentence.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    original_text = "@Natalija What a wonderful day, isn't it @Kristina123 ?"
    individual_words = original_text.split(' ')

    words_without_tags = [word for word in individual_words if '@' not in word]

    new_sentence = ' '.join(words_without_tags)
    print(new_sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be work for you. The pattern `@\w+?\s` will determine expressions which start with @ continued by one or more alphanumeric characters then finish with an optional white space.

```
import re

string = "@Natalija What a wonderful day, isn't it @Kristina123 ?"
pattern = '@\w+?\s'

replaced = re.sub(pattern, '', string)
print(replaced)
```